# Can I install ubuntu on a windows 10 tablet?

Tags: boot, touchscreen, tablet

I have a [Linx 1010 tablet](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linx-1010-10-1-Inch-Tablet-Bluetooth/dp/B01272MLDM), no keyboard, no mouse. But the concern is installing Ubuntu: from the moment I plug a USB stick in and boot it up, will it detect my touchscreen so that I can operate on the menu with the following options:

- Install Ubuntu
- Try Ubuntu,etc

Please keep in mind that vector remote works only for windows, I don't have any other keyboard or mouse to operate with.

Comment: As far as I know, GRUB doesn't support touchscreens. You may be able to navigate it by using volume buttons and the Windows key as Enter.

Comment: @creator: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/706709/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is the entire reason the option <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd> exists!

So: make the USB drive, boot it up, choose the <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>  option and if your hardware does not allow you to even choose that option, shut down the tablet, remove the USB drive and boot it back up as the <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd> option *doesn't change anything on your existing machine and runs solely off the USB stick!*

### ;-)